# ZMQ connect and push - how to determine if it fails

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a simple `ZMQ` program that establishes a `zmq.PUSH` socket, `connects`, and then tries to send messages.

```
import zmq

zcontext = zmq.Context()
zsock = zcontext.socket(zmq.PUSH)
zsock.connect("tcp://localhost:12345")

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
   for line in f:
       zsock.send(line)
```

This works fine when the other side is there. But if there's any problems with the listener on the other side (e.g. forgot to start listener, or I connected to wrong port), it just hangs after it tries to send about 1000 messages (depends on size of the default queue).

What's the right thing to do? If there's any issue with other side, I'd rather just print an error message and exit gracefully.

Comment: Did you try with the `flags=NOBLOCK`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `zmq.error` with the following snippet code:

```
import zmq
import time

zcontext = zmq.Context()
zsock = zcontext.socket(zmq.PUSH)
zsock.connect("tcp://localhost:12345")

try:
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        for line in f:
            zsock.send(line, flags=NOBLOCK)
            time.sleep(.1)

except zmq.ZMQError as exc:
    print(exc)
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- You can change the `.connect()` method with the `.bind()` in above code, and also change the other side `bind` to `connect` for a test case.
- In `.bind()` method should be used `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

---

[**UPDATE**]:

- Check the [Limiting_ZeroMQ_Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353685/3702377)

> - With `flags=NOBLOCK` in `.send()` method, this raises `ZMQError` if the **queue is full;** otherwise, this waits until space is available.
>     Thus, in this case, will be as the following:
>
>   `zsock.send(line, flags=NOBLOCK)`

Comment: I don't think that works. Did you try it? It just tries to send it down the socket without throwing an exception

Comment: why not works?! if you have an error on this loop you will know it.

Comment: i tried it. picked a random port with nobody listening. it doesn't throw an exception

Comment: still hanged after 1000 itteration loop?

Comment: yes. i think 1000 might be the default queue size. it goes up to 1000, and then hangs.

Comment: @user3240688 check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353685/3702377) and change the `SNDHWM` and `RCVHWM` from `1` to `2000` and remove the `sock.setsockopt(zmq.CONFLATE, 1)`

Comment: @user3240688 I updated my answer with `flags=NOBLOCK` argument.