# Pyzmq high-water mark not working on pub socket

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

According to the ZeroMQ documentation a pub socket is supposed to drop messages once the number of queued messages reaches the high-water mark.

This doesn't seem to work in the following example (and yes I do set the `hwm` before bind/connect):

```
import time
import pickle
from threading import Thread
import zmq

ctx = zmq.Context()

def pub_thread():
    pub = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
    pub.set_hwm(2)
    pub.bind('tcp://*:5555')

    i = 0
    while True:
        # Send message every 100ms
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pub.send_string("test", zmq.SNDMORE)
        pub.send_pyobj(i)
        i += 1

def sub_thread():
    sub = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
    sub.subscribe("test")
    sub.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')
    while True:
        # Receive messages only every second
        time.sleep(1)
        msg = sub.recv_multipart()
        print("Sub: %d" % pickle.loads(msg[1]))

t_pub = Thread(target=pub_thread)
t_sub = Thread(target=sub_thread)
t_pub.start()
t_sub.start()

while True:
    pass
```

I'm sending messages on pub 10 times faster than reading them on the sub socket, `hwm` is set to 2. I would expect to only receive about every 10th message. Instead, I see the following output:

```
Sub: 0
Sub: 1
Sub: 2
Sub: 3
Sub: 4
Sub: 5
Sub: 6
Sub: 7
Sub: 8
Sub: 9
Sub: 10
Sub: 11
Sub: 12
Sub: 13
Sub: 14
...
```

so I see all messages arriving, thus they are held in some queue until I read them. Same holds true when adding a hwm=2 on the sub socket as well before connect.

What am I doing wrong or am I misunderstanding `hwm`?

I use *pyzmq version 17.1.2*

Comment: Try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353685/3702377) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278859/how-to-have-limited-zmq-zeromq-pyzmq-queue-buffer-size-in-python/48461030#48461030) post.

Comment: I updated my answer. hope help you up.

Answer (score 2):

With borrowing an answer to the [issue which I opened in Github](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/1241), I've updated my answer as follows:

---

> Messages are held in operating system's network buffers. I have found
>   HWMs to be not that useful because of that. Here is modified code
>   where subscriber misses messages:
>
> ```
> import time
> import pickle
> import zmq
> from threading import Thread
> import os
>
> ctx = zmq.Context()
>
> def pub_thread():
>     pub = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
>     pub.setsockopt(zmq.SNDHWM, 2)
>     pub.setsockopt(zmq.SNDBUF, 2*1024)  # See: http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-setsockopt
>     pub.bind('tcp://*:5555')
>     i = 0
>     while True:
>         time.sleep(0.001)
>         pub.send_string(str(i), zmq.SNDMORE)
>         pub.send(os.urandom(1024))
>         i += 1
>
> def sub_thread():
>     sub = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
>     sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')
>     sub.setsockopt(zmq.RCVHWM, 2)
>     sub.setsockopt(zmq.RCVBUF, 2*1024)
>     sub.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')
>     while True:
>         time.sleep(0.1)
>         msg, _ = sub.recv_multipart()
>         print("Received:", msg.decode())
>
> t_pub = Thread(target=pub_thread)
> t_pub.start()
> sub_thread()
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Output looks something like this:
>
> ```
> Received: 0
> Received: 1
> Received: 2
> Received: 3
> Received: 4
> Received: 5
> Received: 6
> Received: 47
> Received: 48
> Received: 64
> Received: 65
> Received: 84
> Received: 85
> Received: 159
> Received: 160
> Received: 270
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Messages are missed because all queues/buffers are full and publisher
>   starts to drop messages (see documentation for ZMQ_PUB:
>   http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket).

---

[**NOTE**]:

- You should use the high-water mark option in listener/subscriber and advertiser/publisher.
- These posts are also relevant ([Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353685/3702377) - [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278859/how-to-have-limited-zmq-zeromq-pyzmq-queue-buffer-size-in-python/48461030#48461030))
- `sock.setsockopt(zmq.CONFLATE, 1)` is another option to get the last message only which defined in subscriber side.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, `set_hwm` is equivalent to `setsockopt` in this case, it internally calls `setsockopt(zmq.SNDHWM, x)` or `setsockopt(zmq.RCVHWM, x)` depending on the socket type. Your code produces the exact same output as mine, adding the `hwm` on the receiver side doesn't change the behavior, as mentioned in my initial post. The conflate setting "Does not supports multi-part messages" according to ZeroMQ docs, so its not an option.

Comment: @Schwingkopf I double check it.

Comment: Do you mean "I have double checked it, it's working" or "I will double check that its still not working, as you state" ?

Comment: @Schwingkopf No, on your case didn't work, I had [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278859/how-to-have-limited-zmq-zeromq-pyzmq-queue-buffer-size-in-python/48461030#48461030), but I couldn't resolve it using `hwm` then my problem fixed using `conflate` option.

Comment: @Schwingkopf Also I open a [github issue](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/1241) in `pyzmq` repository.

Comment: FYI, the minimum buffer on Linux is 2048 for SND and 256 for RCV. So you can't just set the buffer very small to force it to use the high water mark values (as I thought might be possible).