# How to publish and subscribe the latest message correctly using pyzmq?

Tags: python, zeromq, python-multiprocessing, pyzmq, interprocess

I have a process A that publishes a message constantly and processes B and C subscribe to the topic and get the latest message published by the publisher in process A.

So, I set `zmq.CONFLATE` to both publisher and subscriber. However, I found that one subscriber was not able to receive messages.

```py
def publisher(sleep_time=1.0, port="5556"):

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.CONFLATE, 1)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)
    print ("Running publisher on port: ", port)

    while True:
        localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()))
        string = "Message published time: {}".format(localtime)
        socket.send_string("{}".format(string))
        time.sleep(sleep_time)

def subscriber(name="sub", sleep_time=1, ports="5556"):

    print ("Subscriber Name: {}, Sleep Time: {}, Port: {}".format(name, sleep_time, ports))

    context = zmq.Context()
    print ("Connecting to publisher with ports %s" % ports)
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.CONFLATE, 1)
    socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:%s" % ports)

    while True:

        message = socket.recv()
        localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()))
        print ("\nSubscriber [{}]\n[RECV]: {} at [TIME]: {}".format(name, message, localtime))
        time.sleep(sleep_time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Process(target=publisher).start()
    Process(target=subscriber, args=("SUB1", 1.2, )).start()
    Process(target=subscriber, args=("SUB2", 1.1, )).start()
```

I tried to unset the `socket.setsockopt(zmq.CONFLATE, 1)` in the publisher, and that seemed to solve the problem. Both subscribers in processes B and C could receive messages and the messages seemed to be the latest ones.

I'm trying to find out why setting the publisher with `CONFLATE` caused the problem I had. I could not find information about it. Does anyone know what causes this behavior?

Also, I want to know, in the situation of one publisher to multiple subscribers, what is the correct code setup, so that subscriber can always get the latest messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely a timing issue, the ZMQ_CONFLATE socket option limits the **inbound** and outbound queue to 1 message.

The way PUB/SUB works is the subscriber sends a subscription message to the publisher when you set the ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE option. If you start both subscribers at the same time then its possible that one of the subscription messages that arrived on the publisher queue will be discarded.

Try adding a sleep between the starting each subscriber.

From the zeromq docs

> If set, a socket shall keep only one message in its inbound/outbound
>   queue, this message being the last message received/the last message
>   to be sent. Ignores ZMQ_RCVHWM and ZMQ_SNDHWM options. Does not
>   support multi-part messages, in particular, only one part of it is
>   kept in the socket internal queue.

I am not saying this is the solution to you problem, but if that is the case we may need to post a change to libzmq to make the conflate options more granular so you can choose if conflate should be applied to inbound or outbound queues.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how PUB/SUB works, very informative. However, just tried adding sleep in between two subscribers when they start, the problem still persists.

Comment: Ok that's interesting, I would change the PUB to XPUB and poll for incoming subscription messages. That way you can debug and see if both the subscriptions arrive on the publisher. I would also drop the sleeps in the subscribers and use blocking recv(), just in case we are missing a clue/message during that sleep time.

Comment: Thx. I tried to replace PUB with XPUB, and set CONFLATE for XPUB, others remain unchanged (no sleep between subscriber start). Now, both subscribers are able to receive messages. I'm very confused now. XPUB and PUB aren't that different but 
 they behaved differently in this situation. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes XPUB should only add the ability to see in the incoming subscription message but will probably change the timing also. At this point rather than speculating further (and if you have time) I would re write the test using C and the underlying core library libzmq which is currently on v4.3.1 as its possible that the python library is using an older version or the bug is python specific.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you edit the answer with info about XPUB? I'm gonna accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a manner to get "**Last message only**" option in `ZMQ` Subscribe socket (using `CONFLATE` option).

You need it on the subscriber side.

Here is an example:

```
import zmq

port = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
socket.setsockopt(zmq.CONFLATE, 1)  # last msg only.
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)  # must be placed after above options.

while True:
    data = socket.recv()
    print data
```

On the other word, **I removed any buffered queue in subscriber code.**

---

[**In Additional**]:

With the `zmq.SNDBUF` and `zmq.RCVBUF` options we could set a limit on ZMQ buffer size. ([More complete and an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53360536/3702377))

---